# CSS z-index issue when tooltip inside of table cell

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have a dynamic data table with some custom validation tooltip inside each column. Up on mouse hover the validation message will be displayed. But the adjacent messages near to the table border cutting the full view of messages. Screenshot of the issue with is attached.

find the css code below:

```
  a.tooltips div {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #f87a7a;
    background: white;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: visible;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #f87a7a;
    border: solid 1px #f87a7a;
    /* max-width: 15%; */
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  a.tooltips div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    width: 189px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid #f87a7a;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }

.insight-list-items {
  .smo-normal-table
    .smo-table-normal
    .smo-table-tbody
    > tr
    > td:hover
  {
    z-index: 199999999999999999999999;
    a.tooltips div {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      z-index: 199999999999999999999999;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: z-index doesn't work to show elements which stick out of a scrollable element, what are you using for the tool tip?

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer Its my own cusom tooltip and its css also updated on the Question

Comment: It would be useful to see the HTML as well, but ultimately the answer is the same, anything that is inside a scrollable element that has a child that is somehow positioned to fall outside of the element a z-index won't help to show it on top as it is hidden due to it flowing out of the parent container, the only solution (though maybe a bit a complicated one) would be to use a library like popperjs https://popper.js.org to position the tooltip dinamycly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attached the code, so i cant see how you did this, but my idea would be to give the tooltip a `max-width` property of `100%`.

With this property, the tooltip will never be wider than the table-cell.

Comment: My table is a scrollable table and the scrollbar covers the message it come near to the scroll bar as well.Any option to show it like giving z-index like that. z index also not working fine for me